# swift automatically resize UITextView and states TableView cell while user is typing

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

I'm looking for the best approach to dynamically increase the height of both the UITextView and the TableView Cell height while the user is entering data. Ive searched and found a lot of different answers some more complex than others.

My table has Static Cells

1. TextView1

Ive added the following to my viewDidLoad

```
    renewalsStratTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
    renewalsStratTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But that doesn't seem to do much of anything. I am also not sure on how to dynamically increase the UITextView as the user adds text.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a tutorial that addresses the exact issue you're having. Most of the answers are too complex and perform unnecessary size calculations on text views.

You're already on a good path by setting the estimated row height and row height to automatic dimension, but there are a few other steps to make your table view fully dynamic.

For example, you have to disable scrolling in the text view and you have to call `renewalsStratTableView.beginUpdates()` and `renewalsStratTableView.endUpdates()` every time your user changes text.

For a detailed explanation and a fully working sample code, check out my [post](http://candycode.io/self-sizing-uitextview-in-a-uitableview-using-auto-layout-like-reminders-app/).